# Unable to restore to system to earlier date due to: C:\$Extend\$RmMetada\$Txf

Tags: windows-7, system-restore

How do I remove `C:\$Extend\$RmMetadata\Txf` so that I can perform system restore, associated with error `0x80070005`?

Answer (score 1):

It can't be removed as it contains vital system data.

Alternatively there are fixes for that error.

http://www.wiki-errors.com/wiki-errors.php?wiki=0x80070005